# JQuery Check Checkbox And Add Textbox Name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

Hello guys i wanna do something. I want to check checkbox and add name in same div textbox.
I want to this js wordk all checkbox.

My codes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

   if($(".checkbox").attr('checked')) {

      document.getElementById('text').setAttribute("name","imagename[]");
   } else {
       document.getElementById('text').setAttribute("name","");
   }


});
```

And php codes:

```
for ($i=0;$i < 50;$i++){
echo '<div class="container">'.'<img style="height:100px; width:100px;" src="'.$image[$i].'"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="image[]" value="'.$image[$i].'"><input type="text" id="text" style="width: 100px;"></div>';
}
```

Any advice?
Sorry for my bad English.

Can anyone show on this example?

```
    <form id="form_id"> 
<div class="select_all"><input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll(form_id);'></div>   
    <div class="container"><img style="height:100px; width:100px;" src="http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/54/c6/79/54c67918de386f6c279447b1588805e3.jpg"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox0" class="checkbox" name="image[]" value="http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/54/c6/79/54c67918de386f6c279447b1588805e3.jpg"><input type="text" id="text" style="width: 100px;"></div>
        <div class="container"><img style="height:100px; width:100px;" src="http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/da/07/31/da07314554c2eb1bfc6db8e265058189.jpg"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="checkbox" name="image[]" value="http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/da/07/31/da07314554c2eb1bfc6db8e265058189.jpg"><input type="text" id="text" style="width: 100px;"></div>
        <div class="container"><img style="height:100px; width:100px;" src="http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/6e/f1/af/6ef1afbe4a80e3a728cd58683e26487d.jpg"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="checkbox" name="image[]" value="http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/6e/f1/af/6ef1afbe4a80e3a728cd58683e26487d.jpg"><input type="text" id="text" style="width: 100px;"></div>
        <div class="container"><img style="height:100px; width:100px;" src="http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/03/c9/17/03c917826ca4a7815cd6614330228b08.jpg"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" class="checkbox" name="image[]" value="http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/03/c9/17/03c917826ca4a7815cd6614330228b08.jpg"><input type="text" id="text" style="width: 100px;"></div>
        <div class="container"><img style="height:100px; width:100px;" src="http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/af/9a/43/af9a43bdf2b446dcc8649ecfa800fc97.jpg"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" class="checkbox" name="image[]" value="http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/af/9a/43/af9a43bdf2b446dcc8649ecfa800fc97.jpg"><input type="text" id="text" style="width: 100px;"></div>
    </form>
```

Select all js:

```
    checked=false;
function checkedAll (form_id) {
    var aa= document.getElementById('form_id');
     if (checked == false)
          {checked = true}
        else
          {checked = false}
    for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length; i++) 
    {aa.elements[i].checked = checked;}
      }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with same id on one page, use `id="checkbox-'.$i.'"`. Also for textboxes.

Comment: I can what you say in php but i cant do this in jquery. Can you help me about jquery?

Comment: That was not an answer, just a first observation, answer is coming soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but I'd suggest:

```
// binds an event handler for the change event:
$('.container input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    // finds the input that follows the checkbox elements, sets the name to
    // the 'imagename[]' if it's checked, or to
    // an empty string if not checked
    $(this).next('input').prop('name', this.checked ? 'imagename[]' : '');
// triggers the change event
}).change();
```

Do, however, be aware that you have invalid HTML: an `id` ***must be unique within the document***, unless these input elements need an `id` for other reasons, I'd strongly advise removing them. Otherwise, as noted in the comments, you should include the `$i` in the `id` as it's created.

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Thanks but didnt work. When i was ticking checkbox i coldunt see checkbox checked in chrome code view stuf. I think mistake is around this.

Comment: Sorry i have a mistake. Code is working. Thank lots of.

Comment: I have a select all checkbox. When i tick select all i want to work your code for all texbox. How can i?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery code:

```
$(".checkbox").each(function(){
  $(this).siblings("input[type=text]")
    .attr("name", this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
});
```

There is an anonymous function for each checkbox, inside the function `this` refers to the checkbox itself. You can replace `$(this).val()` with something that holds the image name, for example `$(this).attr("name")` or `$(this).siblings("img").attr("src")`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container').on('change', '.checkbox', function() {
   if(this.checked) {
     $('#text').attr("name","imagename[]");
   } else {
     $('#text').attr("name","");
   }
});
```